# How improve linear regression model in my example

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, scipy

I try to perform an example of linear regression model in python.
The aim is find a linear relationship among two features in my dataset, this features are 'Year' and 'Obesity (%)'. I want train my model to predict the future trend of obesity in the world.
The problem is that my MSE is too high and R2 too low. How can improve my model?

This is the [link](https://www.kaggle.com/amanarora/obesity-among-adults-by-country-19752016/data?select=obesity-cleaned.csv) where I found the data set; Obesity-cleaned.csv

CODE

```py
#Analysis of obesity by country

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import preprocessing

address = 'C:/Users/Andre/Desktop/Python/firstMN/obesity-cleaned.csv'
dt = pd.read_csv(address)

#eliminate superfluos data
dt.drop(dt['Obesity (%)'][dt['Obesity (%)'].values == 'No data'].index, inplace=True)  

for i in range(len(dt)):
   dt['Obesity (%)'].values[i] = float(dt['Obesity (%)'].values[i].split()[0])  

obMean = dt['Obesity (%)'].mean() 
print('%0.3f' %obMean, '\n') 

dt['Obesity (%)'] = dt['Obesity (%)'].astype(float)  #converto il tipo in float 

group = dt.groupby('Country')


print(group[['Year', 'Obesity (%)']].mean(), '\n') 

dt1 = dt[dt['Sex'] == 'Both sexes']   

print(dt1[dt1['Obesity (%)'] == dt1['Obesity (%)'].max()], '\n')   

sb.lmplot('Year', 'Obesity (%)', dt1)
plt.show()

#linear regression predictions

group1 = dt1.groupby('Year')

x = np.array(np.linspace(1975, 2016, 2016-1975+1)).tolist() 
y = np.array([group1['Obesity (%)'].mean()]).tolist()[0]

x1 = np.array([1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002 , 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016 ]).reshape((-1, 1))  
y1 = np.array([group1['Obesity (%)'].mean()]).reshape(-1, 1)     

lr = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
lr.fit(x1, y1) 

plt.plot(x, y) 
plt.show() 

print('Coefficients: ', lr.coef_)  
print("Intercept: ", lr.intercept_ )

y_hat = lr.predict(x1)
print('MSE: ', sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(y_hat, y1)) 
print('R^2: ', lr.score(x1, y1) ) 
print('var: ', y1.var())
```

OUTPUT

```
Coefficients:  [[0.00626604]]
Intercept:  0.0
MSE:  15.09451970012738
R^2:  0.03779706109503678
var:  15.687459567838905 

Correlation among years and obesity (%) is:  (0.9960492544111168, 1.0885274634054143e-43)
```

Comment: Why do you have fit intercept false here? That's probably one of the reasons why you're struggling with your fit. But in general, questions like these are hard to answer because they're vague. You may want to rephrase this in a more pointed way.

Answer (score 1):

Your years and obesity are in too totally different scales, if you don't fit with an intercept, it's going to be wrong, you can see it below:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
plt.scatter(x1,y1)
lr = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
plt.plot(x1,lr.fit(x1, y1).predict(x1),color="k")
lr = LinearRegression()
plt.plot(x1,lr.fit(x1, y1).predict(x1),color="g")
plt.legend(['no intercept','with intercept'])
```

[image]